# Why this code throws java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: java, stack-overflow

Why this code doesn't execute fine. It throws java.lang.StackOverflowError. I want to know the behavior of the class.

```
public class A {
A a = new A();
public static void main(String[] args) {
    A a = new A();
    System.out.println("i'm done!");
}}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/214741/what-is-a-stackoverflowerror

Comment: You should learn to use a debugger, then you'd see the obvious problem.

Answer (score 3):

Your creating an instance variable `a` of `A`  and initializing it with every call to the constructor. So it keeps going like a infinite loop

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are facing is that you are redeclaring the class with the default/blank constructor on the second line, causing an infinite loop and thus a StackOverflowError.

Remove to match:

```
public class A {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    A a = new A();
    System.out.println("i'm done!");
}}
```